# Django: Changing of value of particular fields in previous instances of model if particular instance occurs

Tags: python, django, django-models

I' m creating small django project.
Is any way to change value of particular fields in previous instances of particular model?

```
class Fruit (models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=40)
        amount=models.IntegerField()
```

So far for example i have three instances of my model.

```
[0 Object{ "model": "Fruit","pk": 1,"fields": {"name": "Banana", "amount": "2"}},
1 Object{ "model": "Fruit","pk": 2,"fields": {"name": "Apple", "amount": "2"}},
2 Object{ "model": "Fruit","pk": 3,"fields": {"name": "Mango", "amount": "1"}}]
```

And i decided that fourth instance will be Orange in amount 3.

```
[0 Object{ "model": "Fruit","pk": 1,"fields": {"name": "Banana", "amount": "2"}},
1 Object{ "model": "Fruit","pk": 2,"fields": {"name": "Orange", "amount": "2"}},
2 Object{ "model": "Fruit","pk": 3,"fields": {"name": "Orange", "amount": "1"}}
3 Object{ "model": "Fruit","pk": 4,"fields": {"name": "Orange", "amount": "3"}}]
```

As you see my goal is to change all previous names of fruits to Orange in case of creating of instance with Orange as name
until Banana occurs so banana remains unchanged.

Is there any way to do something like that?

Comment: What if before Banana there is Apple? What happens to that Apple?

Comment: Good question. In my my project if Apple was before banana it would remain the same.

Answer (score 0):

you can loop over your `Fruit` object and change all names based on condition

```
for item in Fruit.objects.all():
   if item.name == "Banana":
      pass
   else:
      Fruit.objects.update(..update values)
```

Answer (score 0):

After the new instance is created, you can loop through all instances in reverse order until the keyword (e.g. "Banana") is found. See [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#reverse) for reverse method. Break the loop if the keyword is found, else change the fruit name (e.g. to "Orange").

```
for fruit in Fruit.objects.all().reverse():
    if fruit.name == "Banana":
        break
    else:
        fruit.name = "Orange"
        fruit.save()
```

This solution assumes you want to do the changes immediately after an instance is created (so in your example the fourth instances would be the last instance).